# Verwendung des Konjunktiv 1 in irrealen Vergleichen (»als seien sie niemals getrennt gewesen«)

Tags: subjunctive, grammar-identification

> Es ist für beide fast so, als **seien** sie niemals getrennt gewesen.

Warum wird hier der Konjunktiv 1 verwendet?
Es handelt sich um keine indirekte Rede wo der Konjunktiv 1 hauptsächlich verwendet wird.
Meines Wissens nach sollte hier Konjunktiv 2 verwendet werden, also:

> Es ist für beide fast so, als **wären** sie niemals getrennt gewesen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Von der Konsistenz her gesehen hast Du recht und es müsste der Konjunktiv 2 verwendet werden. Da sie tatsächlich getrennt waren, beschreibt der Nebensatz eine irreale Situation, wofür normalerweise der Konjunktiv 2 verwendet wird. Es liegt keine indirekte Rede (oder ähnliches) vor, die den Konjunktiv 1 verlangen würde.

Einige Präskriptivisten raten deshalb von dieser Verwendung ab, z. B. [Belles Lettres](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/konjunktiv/konjunktiv.php#vergleich):

> Der Konjunktiv 1 hat in Ver­gleichssätzen aller­dings nichts ver­loren. Die Wort­kom­bina­tio­nen *als sei, als habe* usw. sind also immer falsch. Richtig sind *als wäre* und *als hätte*.

**Aber:** Es ist tatsächlich sehr üblich, dass in solchen irrealen Vergleichssätzen der Konjunktiv 1 verwendet wird. So beobachtet zum Beispiel [der Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Nebensatze-mit-als-ob-als-wenn-wie-wenn):

> In irrealen Vergleichssätzen mit *als ob, als wenn* und *wie wenn* wird sowohl der Konjunktiv I als auch der Konjunktiv II verwendet:
>
> > Du tust ja geradezu, als ob du zu gar nichts zu gebrauchen wär[e]st/sei[e]st.
>
> Der Konjunktiv II *([...] zu gebrauchen wärest)* ist aber üblicher. Das gilt auch für irreale Vergleichssätze mit *als* bei folgender Verbform:
>
> > Sie lächelte, als hätte/habe sie niemals lügen müssen.

Warum der Duden hier einen vagen Unterschied zwischen *als* und *als ob* macht, ist mir unklar. Mir ist kein Unterschied in der Verwendung bewusst.

Von diesem deskriptiven Standpunkt ist die Verwendung des Konjunktiv 1 in Vergleichssätzen legitim:
Es ist korrekt, weil es so verwendet wird (und zwar auch in der Hochsprache).
Ob diese Verwendung aus Schludrigkeit, Hyperkorrektur, dem Lateinischen, oder etwas anderem erwachsen ist, kann ich nicht sagen.

Die Antwort auf Deine Frage ist also:
Der Konjunktiv 1 wird hier verwendet, da es sich um einen irrealen Vergleichssatz handelt und diese einen Spezialfall darstellen.

Comment: Ich vermute, die Unterscheidung ist nur der Überschrift geschuldet, laut der es um Nebensätze geht; bei *als* allein ist aber das finite Verb vorangestellt.

Answer (score 1):

Nach meinem persönlichen Sprachempfinden ist der Satz schlicht falsch, und er müsste korrekt lauten: "... als **wären** sie ..."

Comment: Gibt es mehr aufschreibbare Argumente als "persönliches Sprachempfinden"? Ich für meinen Teil finde den Satz grammatikalisch möglich. Bin allerdings in Regeln nicht (mehr) firm, daher kann ich die eigentliche Frage "warum Konjunktiv I" auch nicht beantworten.

Comment: Eine offizielle Regel habe ich hierzu nicht parat. Die gibt es bestimmt, müsste dann aber jemand anders liefern. Ich steuere hier nur meine Kompetenz als "native speaker" bei.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt: **Offizielle** Regeln für Grammatik gibt es im Deutschen sowieso nicht. Allerdings gibt es schon Muster, die man als Regeln formulieren kann und die insbesondere Sprachlernern helfen. Man kann ja nicht jeden Einzelfall auswendig lernen.

Comment: Der Konjunktiv I mag in dieser Verwendung heute ungebräuchlich sein, in der Literatur finden sich aber Beispiele dafür. Z.B. "Dann schien es im wohl, als sei er entrückt ins elysische Land..." (Thomas Mann, *Der Tod in Venedig*)